# How to use after and before pseudo elements with :active?

Tags: html, css

I am creating CSS heart shape using `after` and `before` pseudo elements.
but when I click on the shape only `heart` class's color changes to blue. I also want to change the color of every element of it.
I don't know if we can use `active` and `after` and `before` pseudo element at the same time.I can't use them at the same time what could be the solution of this ?

```css
.heart {
            width:100px;
            height:100px;
            background-color: rgb(255, 136, 156);
            position: absolute;
            top: 20%;
            left: 20%;
            transform: rotate(-45deg);
        }
        .heart::after{
            content: "";
            width:100px;
            height:100px;
            background-color: rgb(255, 136, 156);
            border-radius: 50%;
            top: 0%;
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
        }
        .heart::before {
            content: "";
            width:100px;
            height:100px;
            background-color: rgb(255, 136, 156);
            border-radius: 50%;
            top: -50%;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0%;
        }
        .heart:active {
            background-color: blue;
        }
        .heart::after + .heart:active {
            background-color: blue;
        }
        .heart::after:active {
            background-color: blue;
        }
```

```html
<div class="heart"></div>
```

Comment: you combining wrong way the pseudo class and pseudo element (after, before). you should combine it like this way .example:active::after

Comment: @NIKHILCHANDRAROY yeah... Thanks mate.It was a silly mistake. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set as below, always pseudo element to the end:

```
.heart:active,
.heart:active::after,
.heart:active::before{
   background-color: blue;
}
```

### DEMO:

```css
.heart {
            width:100px;
            height:100px;
            background-color: rgb(255, 136, 156);
            position: absolute;
            top: 20%;
            left: 20%;
            transform: rotate(-45deg);
        }
        .heart::after{
            content: "";
            width:100px;
            height:100px;
            background-color: rgb(255, 136, 156);
            border-radius: 50%;
            top: 0%;
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
        }
        .heart::before {
            content: "";
            width:100px;
            height:100px;
            background-color: rgb(255, 136, 156);
            border-radius: 50%;
            top: -50%;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0%;
        }
        .heart:active,
        .heart:active::after,
        .heart:active::before{
            background-color: blue;
        }
```

```html
<div class="heart"></div>
```

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you.

Comment: @JeetViramgama You welcome, don't forget to validate answer

Comment: sure In some time